# MySQL multiple update queries vs. one insert ... on duplicated key update query

Tags: mysql

I need to update hundreds to thousands rows. I wonder which of the following options is better:

1. sending multiple (hundreds to thousands) "UPDATE" queries
2. sending one (big) "INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" query

More info:

1. The table is InnoDB.
2. The rows are all existing (duplicated). There won't be new rows to be inserted in this operation.
3. About 4 - 10 columns will be involved.
4. Only this one table is involved.
5. I am using PHP to execute the queries.

Insert should be faster because I can batch multiple rows into one single query, but this is a read-heavy table and I am worried about locking. Will the insert query result in more locking problems than the multiple update queries?

Thanks

Comment: That's too less information for a good answer

Comment: @michael what info do you need?

Comment: Are all of the inserts duplicates? What kind of table do you use - myisam, inno_db, ... ? how many columns are affected? are there multiple duplicate possibilities?

Comment: do the queries concern multiple tables ?

Comment: Have you thought about transactions? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-transaction-model.html

Answer (score 0):

Transactions should be used when performing multiple operations against one or more tables to allow you to return the database to a consistent state in case there is an error in one of the operations...

**Advantages**:

Simply we can say the following advantage of transaction 
To maintain

- database integrity
- atomicity
- durability
- consistency

transactions are useful

**See this (easy) example:**

```
// Set autocommit to off
mysqli_autocommit($con,FALSE);

// Update values 
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE ...");
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE ...");
// or do it with prepared statements and run bind_params(...) and execute() in a loop (anyway the better solution // however your situation is


// Commit transaction
mysqli_commit($con);

// Close connection
mysqli_close($con);
```

See:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-implicit-commit.html

**SIDENOTE:**

If you want to do it without transactions, the updates will be faster for you (compared with insert...)